# ASP Telerik Rad ColorPicker

Tags: c#

I have three radio buttons High, Medium, and Low.  If I check High it should show color which has been recently set in the color picker.  Similarly for other two buttons.  If i check a button only their respective color should  be set in colorpicker control.

Comment: Are you expecting us to write the code?  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Im a beginner in ASP. I had idea of using in Dictionary.But I dunno how to write code for it. can U help???

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. I'd encourage you to use the Telerik Forums for Telerik specific questions. You'll get faster and more focused help.
2. In this case, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Some code showing what you've tried would be useful. In general, it's best to share what you've tried and ask for help if you get stuck.

To give you something to try, make sure you explore the Telerik Online Demos for RadColorPicker. There are demos that show you how to work with the Server and Client-side APIs, giving you all the tools you need to implement your scenario (such as the client-side method `get_selectedColor`):

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/colorpicker/examples/clientsideapi/defaultcs.aspx